# Loop through files in a folder one by one

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, directory, filenames

Hi everyone I have a small issue with a script I wrote.

```
import os
import glob

def loop_dir():
   for file in glob.glob('/Users/++++/+++/test/*.mp4'):
       return str(file).split('/')[-1]


def mk_dir():
    i=1
    keepGoing=True
    while keepGoing:
      path = "Folder_{}/".format(i)
      if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname("Folder_{}/".format(i)), exist_ok=False)
        keepGoing = False
      i += 1
    return str(path)

with os.scandir('/Users/++++/++++/test') as it:
        for vid in it:
            os.system('python3 video2images.py \.    #here goes the filename
                        -i /Users/++++/++++/test/' + loop_dir() + ' \
                        -o /Users/++++/++++/' + mk_dir() + ' \
                        --sample_interval 2 \
                        --max_frames 100')
```

What I would like to do here is to have the first function return one by one the filenames in the directory so they can be inserted in the last chunk at the bottom. 
I have tried several options `os.listdir() os.scandir() glob.iglob()` but I couldn't fix my issue. At the moment the code always loops using the same filename.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The reason its return one file its because of the `logical error` your making in the loop.

I suggest you append the files found to an `array` then return the array. You can then access the files from the array.

```
def loop_dir():
   files=[]
   for file in glob.glob('/Users/++++/+++/test/*.mp4'):
       files.append(str(file).split('/')[-1])
   return files
```